# Responsive Circle inner circle

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to create a responsive circle with an inner circle in it as in jsfiddle.
If I resize the page I want the outer circle and the inner circle to adjust automatically.

How could I achieve that behaviour?

Here is what I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/ineffablep/x03f61db/

### Code:

```js
function createFields() {
  $('.field').remove();
  var container = $('#container');
  for (var i = 0; i < +$('input:text').val() + 1; i++) {
    $('<div/>', {
      'class': 'field',
      'text': i
    }).appendTo(container);
  }
}

function distributeFields() {


  var fields = $('.field'),
    container = $('#container'),
    width = center.width() * 2,
    height = center.height() * 2,
    angle = 0,
    step = (2 * Math.PI) / fields.length;
  var radius = width / 2;
  var containerLength = $('input:text').val();
  angle = step * (containerLength - 1);

  fields.each(function() {

    var x = Math.round(width + radius * Math.cos(angle));
    var y = Math.round(height + radius * Math.sin(angle));
    $(this).css({
      right: x + 'px',
      top: y + 'px'
    });
    angle -= step;

  });
}
var center = $('#center');

$(window).resize(function(height) {

  $('#container').width($(window).height() * 0.9)
  $('#container').height($(window).height() * 0.9)
  var width = $('#container').width() * 0.4;
  console.log("width", $('#container').width());
  console.log("height", $('#container').height());
  var radius = width / 2;
  width += 'px';
  radius += 'px';
  center.css({
    width: width,
    height: width,
    '-moz-border-radius': radius,
    '-webkit-border-radius': radius,
    'border-radius': radius
  });

  createFields();
  distributeFields();
  // rest of your code for font-size setting etc..
});

$(window).resize();


$('input').change(function() {
  createFields();
  distributeFields();
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 2em;
}
#center {
  position: absolute;
  background: #00A8D9;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  top: 55%;
  left: 27%;
}
.field {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
Number of fields:
<input type="text" value="60" />
<div id="container">
  <div id="center"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: have you considered doing this in SVG?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/nv8wsawm/) on how you can handle this.

---

What I did first, is to add a css rule for your `#container` :

```
#container{
    position:relative;
    float:right;
}
```

Then, I edited `top` and `left` CSS values for `#center` element, and added a `box-sizing` attribute (to prevent `border` from crashing `width` behavior) :

```
#center { 
    position:absolute;
    background: #00A8D9;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border:3px solid #000;
    top:100%;
    left:0%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

---

I found that the center of your fields circle is at the bottom-left corner of the `#container`, so I reproduce this behavior for the `#center` element. That's why it is positioned `top:100%` and `left:0%`, but in order to be exactly centered on the bottom-left corner, I need to add negative margins (half the `#center` size), that are calculated depending on the `#container` size :

```
$(window).resize(function(height) {

    $('#container').width($(window).height()*0.9);
    $('#container').height($(window).height()*0.9);
    var width = $('#container').width() * 0.4;
    var radius = width;
    var topPos = (width/2)*(-1.2);
    var rightPos = (width/2)*(-1.2);
    radius += 'px';
    topPos+="px";
    rightPos+="px";
    $('#center').css({
        left:'0%',
        top: '100%',
        'margin-top':topPos,
        'margin-left':rightPos,
        '-moz-border-radius' : radius,
        '-webkit-border-radius' : radius,
        'border-radius' : radius
    });

    createFields();
    distributeFields();
    // rest of your code for font-size setting etc..
});
```

PS : *I found that the center of your fields circle is at the bottom-left corner of the `#container`*  | That'is not exactly the case, dealing with some pixels. The way you are positioning your fields may be causing this small gap. You just have to find a way to adapt margins using the same logic you are positioning your fields

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it with SCSS. You just need to create one variable.

```css
$width: calc(100vw / 5);
.circle {
  width: $width;
  height: $width;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

[Please see the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mangesh1556/ztv8okgo/22/)